# Regex match content between specific XML tags

Tags: python, regex, xml

Is there any possibility to match some content between XML tags, depending on specific value. Code to match:

```
  <data>
    <ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
      <ns3:statusCode>200</ns3:statusCode>
      <ns3:messageId>65683</ns3:messageId>
    </ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
  </data>
  <data>
    <ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
      <ns3:statusCode>200</ns3:statusCode>
      <ns3:messageId>65685</ns3:messageId>
    </ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
  </data>
```

I want to match that part, but depending on messageID value (e.g.65685 like in example above):

```
    <ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
      <ns3:statusCode>XXX</ns3:statusCode>
      <ns3:messageId>XXXX</ns3:messageId>
    </ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
```

I have tried a lot of possible expressions but none of them work. Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: [You may want to reconsider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Are you trying to match two <data>...</data> blocks? Or you want to parse the number values?

Comment: I want to match the whole block <ns3:createGroupMessageRes>....</ns3:createGroupMessageRes> but only this one with value 65685 in messageId field.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I second Chris Lear. Without language it's difficult to propose a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my post below. I have posted two solutions. one return with contents with data and other without data tags.

Comment: xslt seems to be ideal for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
# tested with python 2.7x
import re
stringIn = """
  <data>
    <ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
      <ns3:statusCode>200</ns3:statusCode>
      <ns3:messageId>65683</ns3:messageId>
    </ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
  </data>
  <data>
    <ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
      <ns3:statusCode>200</ns3:statusCode>
      <ns3:messageId>65685</ns3:messageId>
    </ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
  </data>
  """
q = lambda mId:  [ block[1] for block in re.findall(r'<(?P<p>[^>]+)>\n((?:\s*<ns3:.*)*>%i</ns3:messageId>\s+</ns3:.*)\s+</(?P=p)>' % (mId), stringIn) ]
print q(65685)
```

Output:

```
['    <ns3:createGroupMessageRes>
        <ns3:statusCode>200</ns3:statusCode>
        <ns3:messageId>65685</ns3:messageId>
      </ns3:createGroupMessageRes>']
```